# Why is my bubblesort "if" statement not working?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, bubble-sort

I'm trying to get a bubble-sort method working. The problem occurs in the `if` statement where I have to compare a number and the number on the next index. Here's the code:

```
numbers = [4, 2, 3, 1, 9]

def bubble_sort(arr)

  arr.each do |i|

    arr.each_index do |j|

      if arr[j] > arr[j+1]
        puts "works"
      end

    end     
  end
end #end method 

bubble_sort(numbers)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
sorting.rb:11:in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
    from sorting.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in bubble_sort'
    from sorting.rb:9:in `each'
    from sorting.rb:9:in `block in bubble_sort'
    from sorting.rb:7:in `each_index'
    from sorting.rb:7:in `bubble_sort'
    from sorting.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

By looking at the error message it seems I get an error because I compare to nil, but I don't see why.

Comment: When `arr.each_index do |j|` is reaches the last index, `arr[j+1]` will return nil, because that index doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh is see, but how could i circumvent this? like arr.each_index-1?

Comment: August is correct. You can avoid it by using arr.each_with_index which returns the index of the particular element. When it's at arr.length -1 (last element), you stop. But with a bubble sort, you don't always have to go to the end of the array in later passes through the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use an enumerator to make iteration efficient. See [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html). Here we use `Array#each_index` to extract an enumerator from the array. The solution is based from the Bubble sort described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

numbers = [4, 2, 3, 1, 9]

def bubble_sort(arr)
  return unless arr.size > 1
  indices = arr.each_index
  begin
    swapped = false
    i = indices.next
    indices.each do |j|
      a = arr[i]
      b = arr[j]
      if a > b
        arr[i] = b
        arr[j] = a
        swapped = true
      end
      i = j
    end
    indices.rewind
  end while swapped
end

bubble_sort(numbers)

puts numbers.inspect
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `are[j+1]` doesn't exist, it returns `nil`, which cannot be compared with a number.

To fix it, try changing your code a bit:

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  arr.each do |i|
    arr.each_index do |j|
      begin
        puts "works" if arr[j] > arr[j+1] 
      rescue ArgumentError => e
        # HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
      end
    end     
  end
end
```

That `rescue` will rescue your code from an `ArgumentError` on that line, thus, to a certain extent, fixing your code. I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve with this code, so I'm not going to write it for you.

However, if you do want a ready-made method to sort, like you seem to need, here's a solution:

```
[1,3,2,5,4].sort         #=> [1,2,3,4,5]
# and for descending order, just do:
[1,3,2,5,4].sort.reverse #=> [5,4,3,2,1]
%w[little adam apple boy].sort #=> ["adam", "apple", "boy", "little"]
```

Comment: Please, don't teach such bad habits on a site for professional programmers. First, catching *all* exceptions instead of just the specific exception, second hiding the bug which causes the exception instead if fixing the underlying issue.